# Como coloco os dados de um form em php numa tabela do HeidiSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho um formulário de contacto em *php*, em que quando submetemos enviamos um email com os dados introduzidos.

O que eu queria era inserir esses dados numa tabela no programa *HeidiSQL*.

Código do form:

```
     <div class="pagina" id="contactos">
      <head>  
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  


    <font align= center face= "Comic Sans MS" size=+1 Color= #003d99>
    <?php echo "<p>Contacte-nos</p>"; ?>

</head>


        <Fieldset>             
        <div align="left">
        <form> 
            <legend align="left"> Submeter Coment&agraverios </legend>
            <br />
            <form id="submit_form">     
                    Nome: <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Jo&atilde;o Santos"required="" id="name" class="form-control" type="text" size =20 />  
                     <br />  
                    Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="nome@email.com" size=20 required id="email" class="form-control" />
                     <br /> 
                     <br />
                    <input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="Remember Me" VALUE="op1" NOT_CHECKED> Remind me    
                    <input Type="Reset" Value="Limpar" />

                </form>  
        </Fieldset>
        <div align="left">
        <br>
        <legend align="left"> Coment&aacuterios  </legend>
        <Textarea id="comentarios" name="comentarios"  value="" cols=35 rows=5 ></Textarea>
        <br>
        <br> 
        <fieldset> 
            <legend align="left"> Bot&otilde;es de comando </legend>            
            <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                     <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>  
                     <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>

        </fieldset>
        <?php echo htmlentities($user_message)?></textarea>
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>        

<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#submit').click(function(){  
           var name = $('#name').val();  
           var email = $('#email').val();  
           var comentarios = $('#comentarios').val();
           if(name == '' || email == '' || comentarios == '')  
           {  
                $('#error_message').html("Necessita de preencher todos os campos");  
           }  
           else  
           {  

                $.ajax({  
                     url:"Succesmsg.php",  
                     method:"POST",                                         
                     data:{name:name, email:email, comentarios:comentarios},  
                     success:function(data){  
                          $("form").trigger("reset");  
                          $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);  
                          setTimeout(function(){  
                               $('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow");  
                          }, 9999);  
                     }  
                });  
           }  
      });  
 });  
 </script>  
</div>
```

Comment: É uma inserção normal em banco de dados MySQL, o HeidiSQL não é um banco em si, você não vai colocar dados em uma tabela dele e sim em um banco de dados e ele vai apenas exibir essa tabela pra você de uma forma amigável. Sugiro que estude mais sobre banco de dados, para gravar informações do formulário em uma tabela pode usar essa biblioteca que fiz: https://github.com/LeonardoVilarinho/MinPDO

Comment: Para fazer insert, voce edita o mipdo.php e coloca as credenciais do seu banco de dados (se nao tiver mudado nada nas configurações então é so deixar como esta) então vc usa `MinPDO::insert("tabela", array("coluna1", "coluna2"), array("valor1", "valor2");`

Comment: Ivcs pode por favor disponibilizar o codigo do mipdo.php?

Comment: Só pegar no link do github que citei no primeiro comentário. Daí clica em Clone or download e em seguida em Download ZIP

Comment: Sim percebi, qual a diferença entre a variavel $sgbd e a $dbname

Comment: sgbd é o tipo de banco que no seu caso é "mysql" e o "dbname" é o nome que você deu para seu banco de dados.

Comment: Nao funciona quando executo o exemplo e clico na 1.(insert) da este erro "
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting ',' or ')' in H:\working2014\@estagios\exercicios\testes\php\minpdo.php on line 15"        o codigo é $conn = new PDO(self::$mysql.":host=".self::$mail.fusadeen.pt.";dbname=".self::$exercicios.";charset=utf8;", self::$lele@hghg.com, self::$pass);

Comment: não é assim, você está com entendimento errado sobre `php`,  segue o tutorial que tem no github:https://github.com/LeonardoVilarinho/MinPDO/wiki se não entender o tutorial sugiro que estude mais sobre php e linguagens de programação em si

Comment: Estou a entender sim, mas como faço? Como incorporo esse codigo no meu? Faço um require do ficheiro minpdo.php no meu index.php?